# PHP Code stuck in Cache [Memcached] (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, caching, nginx, memcached

Been having a bit of a problem with my site regarding our caching method and my php code not refreshing or flushing.

To start, my site is a WordPress site on a dedicated Nginx webserver. I used W3 Total Cache for the initial caching setup. Everything was set up to cache through Memcached.
(I should note, my website is somewhat of a 'guest' on this server, which is bit of a semi-community donation semi-sponsored server that runs some other things. The admins are skilled but also volunteers. I have their full support for fixing things, but they don't have time to troubleshoot my very odd issue (especially because I asked for caching to get turned on for the site myself). If we had some hints on what to go on it would make things easier for us than taking shots in the dark ;) So any suggestions are welcomed.)

At some point we noticed that changes to php pages and Wordpress & Plugin updates were not working at all, while the code on the server reflected updates, the pages still processed through the older php code.

This presented a couple unique issues. W3 Total Cache stores it settings in php files. Other php files, when deleted, stop working, but when they are restored to the server, memcached still insists on using its ultra-old memcached copy. The W3 Total Cache settings, whether i removed or altered the settings php files, would NOT stop running everything through cached memcached data.

The server admin attempt rebooting memcached and then flushing it. Neither of those seemed to have any effect. All the other basic settings seem to be set-up correctly.

We can, of course, still add new plugins, all the data that comes from the database works just fine.

At least one other site on the server that is not wordpress also uses memcached with no issues.

Any help is appreciated, should be able to provide further information if it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have apc.stat = 0 in your settings? Does restarting php engine help?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Frederick.  I am checking this with my web admin... just based on some googling it looks like APC.STAT=0 may be a common problem that fits our symptoms!  I even found an old thread you participated in: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-settings-dont-get-saved    If this is our issue, do you have any thoughts on an alternate valid work around that might not effect performance?  The nature of our site (a fansite for a popular gaming podcast) leads to some big traffic spikes that have caused crashes in the past, the server also hosts other

Comment: other websites, a very advanced (read, resource intensive) minecraft server, email, and I'm sure a few other things, so performance is definitely a consideration (even more-so considering our former issues with crashing).  Thanks so much for the lead, regardless!  Will get back to you with results!!

Comment: Frederick:  Looks like this was the issue!  Apparently my web admin had been working on another angle, and he's developed a script to manually flush the APC cache when I do updates and minor tweaks (as, apparently, setting the APC.STAT to 1 would indeed cause performance issues on our server).  It is nice to have an clear technical answer on why we were having issues though!  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound really obvious but you didn't mention it so:

Did you try turning off the Total Cache plugin entirely to confirm you can see the changes when caching is disabled?

Until you've done that and made sure you get the results you expect, there's no way to know that memcached is really the problem.

Comment: I've turned it off, deleted it entirely, reinstalled it.  All of those steps were followed by a good 15 minute wait.  -- Actually, I once deleted the entire site, put up a plain HTML splash screen, waited a few hours, and reuploaded everything (having updating wordpress and plugins in the process).  No updates 'took', memcached still used the old version of the code.  Unlike most plugins that store their settings in the database, Total Cache stores them in a .php file :(

Comment: Honestly, I can't even begin to guess at what's happening with your setup. I've used Total Cache on literally dozens of WP installs and never ever had a problem, much less a problem as wacky as this one! Here's another idea: Try enabling the plugin again but going to its settings and flushing its cache. Does that work? If it does that should help you on your way to finding the real issue . ..